# decrypted message by openssl_encrypt AES-256-CBC

Tags: reactjs, laravel, authentication, encryption

I encrypt my response from my server side (Laravel) to order by decrypting that response by client side (react),
but I got this:

> "**Decrypted Message: Decryption error: Empty message**"

**Laravel**
file name *routes/web.php*

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException;

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');

Route::get('/', function () {
    $message = 'Secret message';
    $encryptionKey = 'dummykey12345678'; // Replace with your valid AES key
    $iv = '1234567812345678';

    // Ensure the key is of valid length
    if (strlen($encryptionKey) !== 16 && strlen($encryptionKey) !== 24 && strlen($encryptionKey) !== 32) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid AES key']);
    }

    $encryptedMessage = openssl_encrypt($message, 'AES-256-CBC', $encryptionKey, 0, $iv);

    return response()->json(['encryptedMessage' => $encryptedMessage, 'iv' => $iv]);
});
```

output from `http://192.168.8.183:8000/`

```
{"encryptedMessage":"d06MJ4mj2lPLfzEb3W\/vcw==","iv":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"}
```

**React.js**
file name *src/App.js*

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

function App() {
  const [decryptedMessage, setDecryptedMessage] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    // Call the API endpoint to get the encrypted message and IV
    fetch('http://192.168.8.183:8000/') // Replace with your actual API endpoint
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const { encryptedMessage, iv } = data;

        // Replace with your valid AES key of 16, 24, or 32 bytes length
        const encryptionKey = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('dummykey12345678');

        try {
          // Decrypt the message
          const decryptedBytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedMessage, encryptionKey, {
            iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv)
          });

          // Convert decrypted bytes to plaintext
          const decryptedMessage = decryptedBytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

          // Update the decrypted message state
          if (decryptedMessage) {
            setDecryptedMessage(decryptedMessage);
          } else {
            setDecryptedMessage('Decryption error: Empty message');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Decryption error:', error);
          setDecryptedMessage('Decryption error: ' + error.message);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Decrypted Message: {decryptedMessage}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When encountering the error "Decryption error: Empty message" in the context of encrypting and decrypting data between Laravel and React, there are a few things you can check and consider to resolve the issue:

Comment: `haha` is an invalid AES key. Is your actual key also invalid (valid AES keys are 16, 24 or 32 bytes in size)? Post a dummy key with the *exact* length of the *actual* key. This is important because PHP/OpenSSL *silently* corrects invalid keys, which would need to be *explicitly* implemented on the CryptoJS side. Also, the key material in the CryptoJS code must be passed as `WordArray` (otherwise it will be interpreted as password and a key derivation function will be applied).

Comment: @Topaco
 
Replace it with a valid AES key of 16, 24, or 32 bytes length,
**But still nothing...?**

`const encryptionKey = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('dummykey123456789');`

I used to validate AES on Laravel ;

    `if (strlen($encryptionKey) !== 16 && strlen($encryptionKey) !== 24 && strlen($encryptionKey) !== 32) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid AES key']);
    }`

Comment: If you'll pardon the question: _why would you need this_? HTTPS traffic is already uniquely encrypted between the client and the server, what does this get you that HTTPS doesn't already get you? (because this feels like something you're tempted to actually use, in which case you really shouldn't)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans
I want to use that for my API it sends permissions and some data from server side (Laravel)
so to hide all this i need to use this security method to fetch it with client side (React)
**those are from different servers**

Comment: No, you don't. As long as both servers communicate over an encrypted channel (HTTPS, WSS, secure database connector, etc.) the encryption is already handled by the servers themselves and you have no reason to roll your own.

Comment: there are not using https yet and the both sides are using different port and IP they communicate with API

Comment: Your test data is inconsistent. The PHP code uses a different IV (`1234567812345678`) than specified  in the test data (`aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`). None of them produce the ciphertext that is specified in the test data. Such sloppiness complicates troubleshooting.

Comment: If you use a 16 bytes key, you have to specify AES-128-CBC in the PHP code (if you want to apply AES-256-CBC, you need a 32 bytes key). Otherwise the key will be silently corrected in the PHP code. CryptoJS does not perform these corrections implicitly, so the keys differ and decryption fails.

Comment: In the CryptoJS code the IV must be Utf8 decoded (currently it is hex decoded, but in the PHP code I don't see a corresponding hex encoding anywhere). By the way, a static IV is a vulnerability. Instead, the IV should be generated randomly. This should then be Base64 encoded on the PHP side for sending, and Base64 decoded on the CryptoJS side (Utf8 is inappropriate for arbitrary bytes). Alternatively, IV and ciphertext can be concatenated before encoding.